# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to an object

Tags: java

I have a function with following signature:

```
class ABC : public static List<ObjectXYZ> getObjectXYZList(Param1 param1)
```

I am calling the function in a way :

```
List<ObjectXYZ> objectXYZ = ABC.getObjectXYZList(param1);
```

Now, Ideally it should work as I am assigning a variable of List, the return value of a function of type List, However I am getting the following error

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.org.lib.ObjectXYZ**

Can someone suggest what might be wrong here ? May be I need to do an enforced casting around the return object ?

**Updated code as MCVE, hope this is more clear**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.someorg.common.ObjectXYZ

// Calling method
List<ObjectXYZ> opaqueVoList = ABC.getObjectList(response);

// Called Method
class ABC {
    public static List<ObjectXYZ> getObjectList(Response response)
            throws RetryException {
        if (some_condition)
                List<ObjectXYZ> listObj = new ArrayList<ObjectXYZ>();
                //magical stuff
                return listObj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Error does not match posted code. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Doctoring code doesn't help in situations like this, it makes your question and error seem unclear. Show real code

Comment: Are you sure you use a simple list everywhere an not an arraylist?

Comment: Also, `com.org.` so, your site is profit-oriented or not? (com is for commercial purposes, org is for non-profit organizations)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch updated the code. Damn i thought i got it right first time. :(

Comment: does it compile? return ObjectXYZ; does not look good.
If you want to rentrun list containg instace of ObjectXYZ then you must create list, create instance of ObjectXYZ , add that instance to list and return list.

Do not return null from method that is returning list. return empty list instead.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki Yes it does and just realized the dev who wrote code, used wrong naming conventions. Although it is List<ObjectXYZ> it was named as ObjectXYZ which caused some confusion. Updating example.

Comment: how ObjectXYZ (object you are returning) is declared? what signature ObjectXYZ (type) has? somebody make it really strange to reason about:)

Comment: @CodeMonkey "the dev who wrote code", why not ask **that** dev?

Comment: @BartoszBilicki Updated the code and thanks for looking

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Only if that dev was around :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into stacktrace to see exact line where the problem occurs. 
First line of stacktrace should point you exactly to root cause. You may update sample code with that line, or update question with relevant part of stacktrace.
Somebody is just casting ObjectXYZ to ArrayList, it seems.

Also, do not return null from method that is returning list. return Collections.emptyList() instead.

RetryException - is this org.springframework.batch.retry.RetryException ?
No need to declare method to throw it, it is RuntimeException.